# Though java.lang.NoSuchMethodError is thrown for direct invocation, the method can be invoked via Reflection

Tags: java

This code:

```
Boolean isSecure = configInstance.isSecure();
```

fails with this error:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.Config.isSecure()Z
```

but, I can invoke the same via reflection when in debug mode.

```
org.Config.class.getMethod("isSecure").invoke(configInstance);
```

This is the method signature:

```
public Boolean isSecure();
```

Some context: This is part of a bean class. Previously, this method returned the boolean primitive type. But, I wanted to capture the scenario where the bean's field value is not set. What did I do wrong here?

Edit 1:

Here's a sample code. I'm on Mac using JDK 1.8.0_60.

```
try {
    isSecure = (Boolean) configInstance.getClass().getMethod("isSecure").invoke(configInstance);
    log.info("isSecure " + isSecure);     // prints true 
    isSecure = configInstance.isSecure(); // error NoSuchMethodError
} catch (IllegalAccessException | InvocationTargetException | NoSuchMethodException e) {
    log.error(e.getMessage(), e);
}
```

Comment: `Boolean isSecure = configInstance.isSecure();`
Does it compile without any errors?

Comment: Sounds like something wasn't compiled, not enough information to diagnose this.

Comment: Of course it was compiled.

Comment: @Uata yes, it does. Initially, it returned the primitive type boolean. I changed the method signature to return a Boolean object instead. That change should not affect the line you pointed out anyway because of autoboxing!

Comment: @john16384 well, I can help give you information. Hopefully the provided information gives you a path to look for. I'm at a loss here.

Comment: Put the reflection code and the normal call together in one program and see if only one fails.  Also print the Method returned from `org.Config.class.getMethod("isSecure")`.

Comment: @john16384 Done. See the code in edit 1.  Even though I changed the `isSecure` signature to return a Boolean, the above code was compiled against the old library version via maven. Can that cause this?

Comment: Yes, I would say that is probably the cause.  You need to recompile that library as well.  Reflection is probably a bit more forgiving in this case (I was first thinking it might be finding somekind of `static` method with the same signature).

Comment: @john16384 thanks. I'll do that. But, I'd like an explanation on why that is. If you or someone can add that as an answer, I'll accept it. Thanks

Comment: That is actually the reason I asked you to print the result from `getMethod`, you however printed the result of `invoke`.  I suspected the signatures to be different, ie `org.Config.isSecure()Z` instead of `org.Config.isSecure()Ljava.lang.Boolean;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A method was changed from `boolean xyz()` to `Boolean xyz()`, but wasn't recompiled into a new JAR.  The signature of these methods is slightly different.  The first one is:

```
xyz()Z
```

The other one is:

```
xyz()Ljava.lang.Boolean;
```

However, when you use reflection, you are looking for a method called `xyz` with no parameters.  In both cases such a method is present.

However, when calling `invoke` there is a subtle difference:

```
Boolean b = (Boolean) SomeClass.class.getMethod("xyz").invoke(instance);
```

The difference is that in the first case, auto-boxing happens from `boolean` to `Boolean`.  In the second case no auto-boxing is needed.

This is why the reflection version works with both versions.

The reason why you donot get a compile error on a normal call like:

```
Boolean b = xyz();
```

...is probably because you have both projects loaded in your IDE.  The IDE will use the locally changed version and compile it correctly.